# How do i get this code to count words not letters?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to get this code to open txt files and rid the files of punctuation, Read those files, create a list of the words, and then count the occurrences of each word. It is counting the occurrences of letters. Also, how do you properly call functions within other functions?

```
import os


# create the dictionary
dictionary = {}
# create dictionary list
dictionarylist = []


def make_a_listh():
   path = 'data/training/'
   Heal = path + 'Health/'
   heal_files = os.listdir(Heal)
   # print(heal_files)
   punctuations = '''!()-—[]{};:'"\,<>.|/?@#$%^&*_~'''
   no_puncth = ""
    line = "--------------------------------------------------- 
--------------------------"
   for j in heal_files:
      file2 = open(Heal + j, 'r').read()
      for char in file2:
          if char not in punctuations:
              no_puncth = no_puncth + char
      print(j + line, "\n", no_puncth)


def make_a_listm():
    path = 'data/training/'
    Minn = path + 'Minnesota/'
    minn_files = os.listdir(Minn)
    # print the filename and a new line
    punctuations = '''!()—-—[]{};:’'"\,<>.|/?@“#$%^&*_~'''
    no_punctm = ""
    line = "--------------------------------------------------- 
    -------------------------"

    for i in minn_files:
       file1 = open(Minn + i, 'r')
       for char in file1:
         if char not in punctuations:
            no_punctm = no_punctm + char
    # print(i + line, "\n", no_punctm.replace('"',''))
    return no_punctm


def Freq(file1):
    # as long as there is a line in file loop
    for line in file1:
        # create variable to hold each word from the file
        words = line.split()
        # as long as there is a word in words loop
        for eachword in words:
            # if there is an existing word in dictionary 
        increase occurrence count
            if eachword in dictionary:
                dictionary[eachword] = dictionary[eachword] + 1
         # if there is a word that is new set count to 1
            else:
                dictionary[eachword] = 1
             # for every item (k and v) in dictionary, loop
     for k, v in dictionary.items():
      # create temporary place holder for v and k values
          temporary = [v, k]
          # (add) temporary values to dictionaryList
          dictionarylist.append(temporary)
          # print out each value from dictionaryList in. 
          descending order on new lines
          print("\n".join(map(str, sorted(dictionarylist, 
          reverse=True))))

Freq(file1=make_a_listm())
```

Comment: The common algorithm to count no of words is to count no of spaces in line and subtract one from it, in English sentences you can see that words are just one more than sentences. Good luck

Comment: [Article for what you're trying to do](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-count-occurrences-of-each-word-in-given-text-file-using-dictionary/)

Comment: Look into a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter) object. Also, you can combine your `make_a_listm` and `make_a_listh` functions by passing them a parameter string (`'Health'` or `'Minnesota'`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `Counter()` method from the collections module, and how you can use `re.sub()` to handle the punctuations more efficiently:

```
from glob import glob
import re
from collections import Counter

words = []

for file in glob("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\*.txt"): # For every file in Folder that ends with .txt
    with open(file, 'r') as r: # Open the file in read mode
        nopunc = re.sub('\W', ' ', r.read()) # Use re.sub to replace all punctuations with spaces
        words += [w.strip().lower() for w in nopunc.split() if w.strip()] # List all the words in lower case, and add the list to words

print(Counter(words)) # prints out a dictionary with each unique word as the keys, and the frequency of those words as values
```